# sas drive i/o error 5 via raid card - sed locked partition table

Tags: dd, scsi, gdisk

I am trying to find a better way to access my newly purchased SAS drives (deepdiscountserver 3tb IBM platters(used or refurb i think yes)), using a 2x4 LSI PCIe3 card.  I think the card is only half working based on a few things mentioned below.

For now, I'm simply trying to put a file system on it, running into `error 5`, and i/o errors(need to remove SED encryption?).  I worked out a way to do it with `dd`, see below.

I don't have options in my SAS/RAID controller card or I would reset it there.  When I press the hotkey during boot, it responds says it will load,  but never loads.  If i understand correctly, this should be where one woud normally turn off the encryption, right?

`sedutil-cli`, and `hdparm` report this, not helpful.

```
sedutil-cli --scan
...
/dev/sdf   No                                                                                             sdc      8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk
The Kernel flag libata.allow_tpm is not set correctly                                                     ├─sdc1   8:33   0   2.7T  0 part
Please see the readme note about setting the libata.allow_tpm  
...
```

```
hdparm -I /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  72 05 20 00 00 00 00 1c 02 06 00 00 cf 00 00 00 03 02 00 01 80 0e 0
0 00 05 20 00 01 ff ff ff ff
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  72 05 20 00 00 00 00 1c 02 06 00 00 cf 00 00 00 03 02 00 01 80 0e 0
0 00 05 20 00 01 ff ff ff ff
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error
```

I will do what worked for me last time.  These drives are going to be a pain in the ass.  See below, and also let me know If I do this a better way;

`dd /dev/sdd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M`

```
dd: error writing ‘/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50084889cf3’: No space left on device
2861589+0 records in
2861588+0 records out
3000592982016 bytes (3.0 TB) copied, 21272.1 s, 141 MB/s
```

SED is gone, should no longer receive I/O errors. Now use `gdisk` to lay in a new partition table.

If you run `gdisk` before you dd the entire drive, it reports the I/O error, usually that means i didnt DD enough of the drive.  usualy I think thats some stuff at the very end of the drive.

```
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): y

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdd.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

I've tried parted, `fdisk`, etc..    If I don't run `dd` at all, or run it just on the beginning, SED takes over I think, and I/O errors, `error 5`, and everything points to bad controller card, cabling, or drive.  However, trying every other cable, and running through `smartctl` says thats a false alarm, that things are fine.

I even have some other IBM drives to compare to on the system, and can tell you, this is normal behaviour, for these drives in their received condition.  If I could get into the SAS settings, I would just clear the drive there.

So in the end, `dd` is all that's working for me, thankfully at least :-)
is  there is a better (quicker) way?  Is it normal to not access to `sedutil`, and `hdparm` for SAS drives?  I better be careful when I choose my next RAID controller card based on this.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find a better way to access my newly purchased SAS
> drives ...

While trying to find information on how to recover a SAS drive to which I (inexplicably) wrote an *.ISO file, I came across your post and thought this information may help you.

The root of the matter seems to be that hdparm, for whatever reason, cannot properly query SAS drives as it is a tool written for ATA/SATA drives.

See here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/hdparm/bugs/73/

> Mark Lord wrote:
> Perhaps the two SAS drives do not implement the SATA IDENTIFY
> command, which is what hdparm is sending them. If they don't have
> that command, they will fail the request.

> sginfo probably sends pure SCSI commands to the drives, which is why
> it works (SAS drives normally speak SCSI).

> hdparm is for ATA/SATA drives, and for any drives/chips that
> understand ATA/SATA commands (including some USB enclosures).

BTW: if you happen to know why I am not able to write the partiton data TestDisk 7.2 found to the drive with the *.ISO file written on it, please do let me know.

Best,

G.